# Why the selector can not be recognized?

Tags: nightwatch.js

When I reference the selector defined in 'elements', it can not be recognized in the second statement but work as expected in the first statement.

```
const vmDetailCmds = {


  command(vm_name,actionButton){

    ....
    //reference @activityTable work as expected here
    this.expect.element("@activityTable").to.be.present.before(1000);

    //reference @activityTable can not be reconginzed here
    this.api.elements("css selector","@activityTable", function(result){
        var count = result.value.length;
        console.log(result);
        console.log("count:"+count);
        ......

    });

    ....


  },
};

module.exports = {
  commands:[vmDetailCmds],
  elements: {
    ....
    activityTable: "ul[aria-label='List  Use arrow keys to navigate']>li[aria-label='Box']";
    ....
  },
};
```

Here is what get printed as the result, any idea on that ?

```
 √ Expected element <ul[aria-label='List  Use arrow keys to navigate']>li[aria-label='Box']> to be present - element was present in 36ms
{ status: -1,
  value: { message: 'invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified\n  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)' },
errorStatus: 32,
error: 'Argument was an invalid selector (e.g. XPath/CSS).' }
count:undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call **this.api.elements(...)** , you are referring to the elements in your browser.

> **activityTable** is an element only available in your own page object and doesn't exist in browser.

Instead you have to put the whole element there:

```
this.api.elements("css selector","ul[aria-label='List  Use arrow keys to navigate']>li[aria-label='Box']", function(result){
...
}
```